# Creating multiple Windows URL shortcuts from a bookmarks HTML file

Tags: html, windows, google-chrome, vbscript, bookmarks

I have a very large number of bookmarks in Google Chrome. I want to transfer all of them to a windows folder, so that each bookmark will be a shortcut to a website (I want a list of shortcuts, just like any list of regular applications shortcuts). I also would like to preserve the bookmark's name and icon.

I searched for a way to achieve my goal, but all I could find is to either *manually* `Create application shortcuts` in Chrome, or to *manually* drag & drop links from the HTML file exported from the bookmarks in the Chrome Bookmark manager to a folder.

Since there's no easy solution (AFAIK), I thought about achieving it in another way.

Basically, what I have, is an HTML file called `bookmarks.html` (created by the `Export bookmarks to HTML file` feature in the `Organize` menu inside the `Bookmark Manager`. It's a long list of links (`<a>`s) - I have more than 250 bookmarks.

I can extract the data I need from the file easily, probably with an XML Parser, though it's possible even with regex, because the structure is known and is the same throughout the whole file:

```
...
<DT><A HREF="http://data.stackexchange.com/" ADD_DATE="1342120101" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0......">Stack Exchange</A>
<DT><A HREF="http://www.istockphoto.com/" ADD_DATE="1285715116" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0.......">Web Design</A>
<DT><A HREF="http://icons.mysitemyway.com/" ADD_DATE="1287435657" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0........">Ico.etc</A>
<DT><A HREF="http://www.shutterstock.com/" ADD_DATE="1285715294" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0.....">Shutterstock</A>
...
```

The problem is that I don't know how to create a script that would take the data - i.e URL, icon (in base64), and name - and make Windows URL shortcuts using that data. I know of few VB scripts that can create a custom shortcut, but not multiple (well, about 300) shortcuts at once.

Comment: Even though Chrome blew me away when it first came out (0.2.149.27) enough to permanently switch to it, it’s been getting worse and worse and the devs have been getting very annoying and tyrannical, so I recently decided to finally give up on it (I’m probably going to Firefox). Therefore I decided to export my Chrome bookmarks to `.url` files to put them with the ones from IE and other browsers that I have made over the years. The first step is to decode the file with your links, and the second is to simply examine the [`.url` file format](http://www.fmtz.com/formats/url-file-format/article).

Comment: All you *need* is the `[InternetShortcut]` header and the `URL` line. If you want to add `Modified`, figuring out the checksum can be hard; it took me hours. [This Japanese page](http://web.archive.org/web/20130521064347/http://hpcgi1.nifty.com/MADIA/DelphiBBS/wwwlng.cgi?print+200506/05060009.txt) was close, but [this one](http://www.atmark.gr.jp/~s2000/r/rtl/InternetShortcut.html) said how. I fixed all the edge-cases, now my Chrome bookmarks are ready to be merged with my old shortcuts. (PS, 300 is “a very large amount”? ಠ_ఠ I have 1,203 in Chrome, and 10,000+ from IE over the past 17 years.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, in combination with a tool like everything that would be usefull, only you will need to do the operation regularly. I suppose it must be possible to get your source right from chrome, anyway here is a script that does what you ask for.

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8, CreateIfNeeded = true
outpath = "g:\script\shortcut\url2\"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
bookmarkfile = "bookmarks.html"
Set bookmarks = objFSO.OpenTextFile(bookmarkfile, ForReading)
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Global = True
Set regEx2 = New RegExp
regEx2.Global = True
regEx2.Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9-_.]"

regEx.Pattern = "<DT><A HREF=""(.*)"" ADD_DATE.*>(.*)</A>"
do until bookmarks.AtEndOfStream
  line = bookmarks.readline()
  if regEx.test(line) then
    shortcut = regEx.Replace(line,"$1")
    filename = trim(regEx.Replace(line,"$2"))
    filename = Regex2.Replace(filename, "_")
    filename = outpath & left(filename, 80) & ".url"
    wscript.echo filename
    'the following skips invalid filenames, you should add a routine to filter out invalid filename characters in your codeset
    on error resume next
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(filename, ForWriting, CreateIfNeeded)
    if err.number <> 0 then
      wscript.echo err.description
    end if
    objFile.write "[InternetShortcut]" & vbcrlf & "URL=" & shortcut
    objFile.close
  end if
loop
```

Comment: What do I need to customize except for the `outpath`? I have the the script inside a `.vbs` file, and I run it in the same folder my `bookmarks.html` file is located at.

Comment: Yes, I am getting `800A0034 VBScript runtime error @ line 13 char 3`. At first I thought it was caused due to the relative/non-relative path thing, but I tried several relative and non-relative output paths.

Comment: i only tried with the 4 lines you provided, you should add a routine to cleanup filename so that all characters conflicting with a filename are removed (you surely will find one on stackoverflow). Add "wscript.echo filename" just before that line so that you see which name gives the problem

Comment: I cleaned the `bookmarks.html` file, and the script is working for 33/300 links - but then it stops. I tried to see if there's anything unusual where it stopped, but there's nothing wrong (even when I deleted the line that caused the problem, it stopped at the same spot. It just stops after 33 shortcuts have been created successfully. Do you have any idea what might cause this? it works great even for links without `ICON`, and the regex seems spot-on. Even when I delete lines 20-40, it still stops after creating 33 shortcuts.

Comment: i see no reason, i suppose you dont put the results on a FAT drive in the roo or something like that, if you don't care to mail me your bookmarks file i'll check it out, meanwhile could you accept the answer ? see my profile for my email address

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15623/discussion-between-amiregelz-and-peter)

Answer (score 0):

Outertech Linkman will handle the job easily. Import the bookmarks file and export your bookmarks to a custom favorites folder. It also supports Edge Chromium with some manual steps.

Answer (score -1):

### - This works really geat -

I exported CHROME BOOKMARKS (also did this to my GOOGLE BOOKMARKS) as a single .html file. This can be done in Chrome through the bookmark manager's ORGANIZE | EXPORT dropdown.
I then opened my USER\Favorites folder. I don't use IE so it had all the default links IE comes with. I created a new folder called CHROME BOOKMARKS.
I opened IE and clicked the star shaped FAVORITES button. I pulled the ADD TO FAVORITES menu down and selected IMPORT AND EXPORT.
This launched an import wizard. I told it I was importing Favorites, and directed it to the .html file Chrome exported (#1), and told it to import to the CHROME BOOKMARKS folder I created (#2).

This created a .url file for each bookmark I had in Chrome which included both the BOOKMARKS BAR and the OTHER BOOKMARKS.

I tested and confirmed that a .URL file is launched in Chrome by double clicking or by drag and drop.

### -This answer is from your question at superuser -

Comment: You have left out a very useful piece of information: Where did Internet Explorer create the .url files? The answer in my case was: C:\Users\scott\Favorites\Bookmarks bar